# How to remove first tag from XML file using java

Tags: java, xml

Can anyone please help me how to remove the first tag from a XML file using java?
Remove:

```xml
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?">
```

from below XML file.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?">
<Tag>
    <subTag>tag1</subTag>
    <subTag>tag2</subTag>
</Tag>
```

Below code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        File file= new File("XMLfile.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc=db.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        /*remove  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?"> */
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's not a tag, it's an XML declaration. It's always helpful to explain WHY you want to do this: if your code is failing because of the presence of the XML declaration, then there is a deeper problem and the "quick fix" of removing the declaration might be inappropriate.

Comment: FWIW, that XML declaration looks invalid anyway, with all those slashes. But yes, Michael's point above is key here.

Answer (score 1):

Before serialising your XML file give your `doc` object to a new instance of `OutputFormat` and then `format.setOmitXMLDeclaration(true)`

For example:

```java
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
format.setIndenting(true);
format.setOmitXMLDeclaration(true);


XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(System.out, format);
serializer.serialize(doc);
```

> Removing the header is valid in XML 1.0, but by doing that, you will lose character encoding data and maybe other things. Please make sure that it is not going to break your system.